# Drop Shadow apply to custom Shape Qml

Tags: qt, qml

It is possible to apply a Drop Shadow effect to a custom shape, because when I tried to do this, there was no shadow  from my Shape.

(I tested the effect on a Rectangle and it works fine.)

```
Shape { 
    id: shape
    ShapePath {
        ...
        fillColor: "blue"
    }
}
DropShadow {
    anchors.fill: shape
    radius: 50
    samples: 20
    horizontalOffset: 5
    verticalOffset: 5
    color: "red"
    source: shape
}
```

Comment: What I found now, is that I need to anchor the object to mainwindow, but if I set to shape an opacity, it will be set after to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Qt version the imports need to be adapted. I've Qt 6.4.0 hence the `Qt5Compat` import for the `GraphicalEffects`. I've also tried your settings for the `DropShadow` and it works (see image below). It could be that your `Shape` is special? You could share more of your code.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Shapes
import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 240

    Shape {
        id: shape
        width: 200
        height: 150
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        ShapePath {
            startX: 20
            startY: 20
            fillColor : "red"
            strokeWidth: -1
            PathLine { x: 180; y: 130 }
            PathLine { x: 20; y: 130 }
            PathLine { x: 20; y: 20 }
        }
    }

    DropShadow {
        anchors.fill: shape
        horizontalOffset: 8
        verticalOffset: 8
        radius: 8.0
        samples: 17
        color: "#80000000"
        source: shape
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]